# Optimize JavaScript if else code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way of writing the below JS code?

```
var check1 = model1.validateAll();
var check2 = model2.validateAll();

if (check1.isValid === false || check2.isValid === false) {
    self.showValidationErrors(check1.messages);
    self.showValidationErrors(check2.messages);
    return true;
}
```

My only concern is once inside the if block, either `check1.messages` **OR** `check2.messages` can have some value (depending on `check1.isValid` **OR** `check2.isValid` is `false`)

Comment: Why not separate if blocks?

Comment: Because in the end I want to return true for any of the if statements...and if both have errors, then the 2nd if block would not get executed

Comment: What is the value of `check1.messages` if `check1.isValid === false`

Answer (score 1):

First, using `=== false` or `=== true` is very rarely necessary. Typically you just test like this: `!check1.isValid` There are use cases for the `=== false` form, but they're rare.

The simple thing here is:

```
if (!check1.isValid && !check2.isValid) {
    if (!check1.isValid) {
        self.showValidationErrors(check1.messages);
    } 
    if (!check2.isValid) {
        self.showValidationErrors(check2.messages);
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Or if you're in an ES5 environment (and what we have below can be shimmed):

```
var invalid = false;
[check1, check2].forEach(function(chk) {
    if (!chk.isValid) {
        self.showValidationErrors(chk.messages);
        invalid = true;
    }
});
if (invalid) {
    return true;
}
```

That may seem inefficient, but as I assume this is in response to a user action, the few milliseconds involved are a non-issue.

Comment: I personally will like go with the `simple thing here`

Answer (score 0):

Use separate `if` blocks. Instead of returning immediately from the block, set a variable and return it when all blocks are done.

```
returnVal = false;
if (check1.isValid) {
    self.showValidationErrors(check1.messages);
    returnVal = true;
}
if (check2.isValid) {
    self.showValidationErrors(check2.messages);
    returnVal = true;
}
return returnVal;
```

Also, when you find yourself creating variables with names like `check1`, `check2`, etc, and doing the same thing with all of them, you probably should be using an array and looping over them.

Answer (score 0):

For something totally different:

```
return [model1, model2].map(function(model) {
    var check = model.validateAll();
    if (!check.isValid) this.showValidationErrors(check.messages);
    return check.isValid;
}, self).indexOf(false) > -1;
```

Check for the meaning of the second argument of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Keep in mind that array methods like `map` and `indexOf` aren't supported by IE8 and lower, but they can easily be polyfilled.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function, that way you won't repeat yourself (DRY).

```
function validateModel(model, self)
{
   var check = model.validateAll();
   if(check === false){
      self.showValidationErrors(check.messages);
   }
}
```

Then you would just call it:

```
validateModel(model1, self);
validateModel(model2, self);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this but only if it's not necessary to check both check-objects in order to write a validation message:

```
var check1 = model1.validateAll();
var check2 = model2.validateAll();

self.showValidationErrors(check1);
self.showValidationErrors(check2);

return !check1.isValid || !check2.isValid;
```

And to the `showValidationError(check)`-function adding this to the first row

```
if (check.isValid) return;
```

I don't think you have to write both messages if just one validation isn't valid, right? If I'm wrong than this way is of course not the best one.